# Css art not working properly, face part not showing up

Tags: css

Am trying to do a Minecraft Steve css art but the face isn't rendering.
I am an amateur by the way.
Here's my code

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 12.5%;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: RGB(255,255,255);
}
.face {
    position: relative;
    height: 80 px;  
    width: 80 px;
    background:  #B4846D;
    top: 240px;
    left: 240px;
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="face"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably due to the space in 80 px. Should be 80px.

Comment: the 'face' shows up if you remove those spaces - but it's way below the container. Don't you want it actually in the container?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of problems.

- The first problem is that your `link` tag is missing the the closing `<`, which may prevent your css from loading correctly
- Another problem is that you have a space between the `80 px` on the `height` and `width` properties. Between the value and the unit there should be no space, so you should have `height: 80px;` and `width: 80px`;
- another "problem" is that i think you want to have the `face` element inside the `container` element. Is it so?
  Maybe you need:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="face"></div>
</div>
```

- The next problem is the way you are positioning the `.face` element. Without an "image" to show us what you want to do it is difficult to know  what you could improve, but i am guessing you want to add `position: absolute` to the `.face` element, so you can place it inside the `.container` element...

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 12.5%;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #B4846D;
  top: 240px;
  left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="face"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed all of the problems that you've mentioned but still nothing showed up. What's the issue

Comment: @NassirBelarbi i have added a snippet example to my answer, so you can see it work

Comment: Maybe it's a problem in my editor, am using code studio for android

Comment: @NassirBelarbi it could be. If you run my snippet here on the browser (press the "Run code snippet") does it work ok?